# Android - Google Keep Style Note Library

Tags: android, user-interface

I am making an app that will allow programmers to easily write code on their phone and push it to a Gist easy. I want to have this have a UI similar to Google Keep, including reorganizing of the cards. Are there any libraries I can use to accomplish this? I have been searching for a while and haven't found anything like how I want. [image: Google Keep Style UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you, its from github :  https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`, you don't need external libraries

Answer (score 1):

simply use `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` :

```
int columnCount = 2;
StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(columnCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recycler_view.setLayoutManager(sglm);
```